# ColorFunction doesn't work with custom PlotMarkers

Tags: plotting, bugs, color, plot-themes

**Bug introduced in 10.3.0 and persisting through 13.0 or later**

---

This works:

```
ListPlot[Range[-10, 10], ColorFunction -> (If[#2 > 0, Red, Green] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

but as soon as I specify custom PlotMarkers, the ColorFunction gets ignored:

```
ListPlot[Range[-10, 10], ColorFunction -> (If[#2 > 0, Red, Green] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotMarkers->"\[Cross]"]
```

What am I doing wrong?
(I use Mathematica 12 on Ubuntu)

Comment: Simplest workaround *for this specific case* is to split the data into two parts and plot them as two datasets. Then use `PlotStyle` for the colour.

Comment: related issue/(bug?) with `PlotMarkers` in v12: `PlotMarkers -> Automatic`  makes all markers Black regardless of `PlotStyle` or `ColotFunction` specification. Compare `ListPlot[{Range[-10, 10], 2 Range[-10,10]}]` and
 `ListPlot[{Range[-10, 10], 2 Range[-10,10]}, PlotMarkers->Automatic]`

Comment: @kglr With version 12.0 on Windows 7 x64 I do not observe this: both set of markers have colors as expected. But in the Cloud I do reproduce the bug.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, just noticed that the issue is with the Cloud frontend; if you copy-as-image the graphics output the coloring is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'll report this to Wolfram Support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Yet another work-around:

```
cf = If[# > 0, Red, Green] &;
data = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, Range[-10, 10]];

ListPlot[List /@ data,  PlotMarkers -> {"*", 24}, PlotStyle -> (cf /@ data[[All, 2]])]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

Another work-around: Use `ListPlot` without the option `PlotMarkers` and post-process the output to replace `Point`s with the desired marker:

```
 ClearAll[replaceMarkers]
 replaceMarkers[marker_] := Module[{colors = 
    Cases[#, HoldPattern[VertexColors -> c_List] :> (RGBColor @@@ c), All][[1]]}, 
   # /. Point[x_, ___] :> (Inset[Style[marker, colors[[#]]], #] & /@ x)] &;
```

***Example:***

```
lp0 = ListPlot[Range[-10, 10], 
   ColorFunction -> (If[#2 > 0, Red, Green] &), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

```
replaceMarkers[Style["*", 24]]@lp0
```

[image]